# Store image with tag and prefix to query fast (s3 aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use Ionic to create a mobile app which can take photo and can upload image from mobile to s3. I wonder how to make a prefix or tag beside the upload image which help me query to this fast and unique. I think about make a prefix and create folder:
           year/month/day/filename ( e.g: 2018/11/27/image.png )
If there are a lot of image in 2018/11/27/ folder, I think it will query slow and sometime the image filename not unique. Any suggest for that ?? Tks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is an excellent storage service, but it is not a database.

You can store objects in Amazon S3 with whatever name you wish, but if you wish to list/sort/find objects quickly you should **store the name of the object, together with its metadata, in a database**. Then you can query the database to find the object of interest.

[DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) would be a good choice because it can be configured for guaranteed speed. You could also put [DAX](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html) in front of DynamoDB for even greater performance.

With information about the objects stored in a database, you can quite frankly **name each individual object anything you wish**. Many people just use a UUID since it just needs to be a unique identifier. The object name itself does not need to convey any meaning - it is simply a Key to identify the object when it needs to be accessed later.

If, however, objects are typically **processed in groups** (such as having daily files grouped together into months for processing with Hadoop clusters), then locating objects in a particular path is useful. It allows the objects to be processed together without having to consult the database.